# CMD get string from file and SET it as a variable to use in cd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm new to batch files and I'm trying to write one to do part of my work (I know lazy right)

So far I have the following...

```
SET skip=1

REM for all the directories indicated to contain core repositories
FOR /F "skip=%skip% delims=" %%i IN (C:\Repos.txt) DO ( 
SET TgtDir =%%i
echo %TgtDir% >> C:\result.txt
)
```

The contents of Repos.txt is:

```
60000
C:\somedir\someotherdir\
C:\a\b\c\
```

Basically I want this script to go through a file, ignoring the first line which will be used for a delay setting later, and extract each line then (ideally) pass it to a cd command but for now I'm just trying to get it into the variable TgtDir.

When i run this script the output in C:\result.txt is:

```
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
```

Any help?

Comment: `SET TgtDir =%%i` sets a variable called `TgtDir ` - note the extra space, so `%TgtDir%` returns nothing as there's nothing called that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) option for batch files. From the aforementioned link:

> Delayed variable expansion is often useful when working with FOR Loops. Normally, an entire FOR loop is evaluated as a single command even if it spans multiple lines of a batch script.

So your script would end up looking like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET skip=1

REM for all the directories indicated to contain core repositories
FOR /F "skip=%skip% delims=" %%i IN (C:\Repos.txt) DO (
    SET TgtDir=%%i
    echo !TgtDir! >> C:\result.txt
)
```

As an alternative, just use the `%%i` variable in your inner loop, rather than creating a new variable.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. In my case the script always failed the first time it was executed in a new cmd.exe. Running it twice in the same cmd.exe would however work. Thanks for this hint. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET skip=1
REM for all the directories indicated to contain core repositories
FOR /F "skip=%skip% delims=" %%i IN (C:\Repos.txt) DO echo %%n>>c:result.txt
```

Comment: Without formatting this is very very difficult to understand.