# DOS / Batch file break out of for loop upon error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch script where I check the length of PDF file names in a dir. If the file name is greater than 3 characters long then I need to break out of the for loop. This should happen at the very first problem file. My issue is that I can't seem to find a way to break out of the loop.

This is the code that I have and the output I get. My problem is that the errorCnt variable that I am using to set between 0 and 1 never changes to 1 even though I am setting it

```
echo STARTING SCRIPT
setlocal

set errorCnt=0
for %%a in (test*.pdf) do (

    echo %%~a

    SET "fullname=%%a"
    SET "name=%%~na

    call :strlen result name

    call :finalresult

    echo Error count is %errorCnt%

    if %errorCnt%==1 (
        echo break
        goto :break
      )

)

:break

goto :EOF


:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)

:finalresult
echo %name% - characters: %result%
if %result% GTR 3 GOTO error1

goto :EOF

:error1
echo ERROR: There are too many characters in this PDF filename.
set errorCnt=1

goto :EOF
```

OUTPUT:

```
STARTING SCRIPT
test1.pdf
test1 - characters: 5
ERROR: There are too many characters in this PDF filename.
Error count is 0
test2.pdf
test2 - characters: 5
ERROR: There are too many characters in this PDF filename.
Error count is 0
```

Comment: The only place you set errorcnt to non-zero is just before the batch file exits, in the :error1 block.

Comment: I set it there since I encountered the error. How should I handle the error check in for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found my answer. The problem is that DOS / Batch treats for loop as one single command. What I mean is that if you set a variable before for loop is called then it remains the same no matter if you change it elsewhere in your code.

The work around is to use EnableDelayedExpansion.

[Batch script for loop won't set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518242/batch-script-for-loop-wont-set-variable)

Once I change my code to this it works great.

```
echo STARTING SCRIPT

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

...
rem notice the ! signs

if !errorCnt!==1 (
        echo break
        goto :break
      )

STARTING SCRIPT
test1.pdf
test1 - characters: 5
ERROR: There are too many characters in this PDF filename.
Error count is 1
break
```