# loop and pad a variable in batch with zeros

Tags: batch-file

Hi I'm trying to loop and pad some variables with 0 in a batch script. I've looked up on stackoverflow to do both but have some trouble weith percents and double percents.

The following fails to pad it with 0s. Where should I add percents here?

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
    set "i=0%i%"
    set "i=%i:~-2%"
    echo "%%i"
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12518242/995714, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13805187/995714

Answer (score 1):

if you change a variable and want to use it in the same block, you have to use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
    set "i=0%%i"
    set "i=!i:~-2!"
    echo "!i!"
)
```

Comment: thanks but no need for the downvote theres no way i could have googled this, i did try

Comment: that wasn't me. Easy to google, if you know the right search term - if you don't, you're lost.

Comment: if you search for something like "variable for loop in batch file" you'll get a lot of answers with delayed expansion and the use of `!` instead of `%`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes - as soon as you know what the problem is, you will easily find the answers. Problem here was masked by confusion with `for` variables and "normal" variables.