# Change variable in batch file for-loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have created a code that takes the following variables:

```
SET sdir=T:\path\to\in\
SET tempdir=T:\path\to\tempBatch\
SET list=DE NL
```

Then, I try to loop through the list items and copy all TXT files in them to the `tempBatch` folder.

```
(for %%l in (%list%) do (
    set tempINdir=%sdir%%%l
    echo %%l
    echo %tempINdir%
))
```

The output I get is:

```
DE
T:\path\to\in\NL
NL
T:\path\to\in\NL
```

Of course, I want to have the `%%l` variable concatenate with the `%sdir%` path:

The output I get is:

```
DE
T:\path\to\in\DE
NL
T:\path\to\in\NL
```

Why does it only take the last item in the list when creating `tempINdir`? I have tried to use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518242/batch-script-for-loop-wont-set-variable), but this doesn't do anything.

Comment: *enabling* [delayed expanison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) is not enough. You also have to *use* it: `echo !tempINdir!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script for loop won't set variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518242/batch-script-for-loop-wont-set-variable)

Comment: @aschipfl, as said in the question: that answer did not help me.

Comment: @Stephan, thanks, that works!

Comment: The linked answer perfectly demonstrates both to enable and to use delayed expansion in order to resolve exactly the same problem...

Comment: No it _shows_ it and it doesn't explain it. It is my non-understanding of the batch syntax that I did not see the different reference characters. Which is why I asked it here. Here it is explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments by Stephan and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/5488275):

> Delayed variables are referenced with !var! instead of %var%

So, in the `for` loop you need to use `!var!` instead of `%var%`.