# batch variable is empty in for loop

Tags: batch-file

So I'm writing a batch file with absolute no knowledge about writing a batch. My goal is pretty simple. I want to execute `arp -a` and loop this. I want to save the IPv4 address to a variable. So I do this:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('arp -a') do (
    set ipAddr=%%i
    echo Test: %ipAddr%
)
```

But this shows me multiple lines with `Test:` , nothing else. It looks like the variable is not filled properly. So I removed `@echo off` just to test and it returns me this:

```
C:\Users\rs\Desktop>(
set ipAddr=someIpAddrHere
 echo Test:
)
Test:
```

So I can see the IP address in the command, but in the output it's empty. What is wrong here?

Comment: google `EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: dupe of [Batch script for loop won't set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518242/batch-script-for-loop-wont-set-variable) or many others

Comment: Great! This helped a lot, thanks! And sorry for the duplicate, didn't find this thread on my researches.